# Refresh token giving invalid grant

Tags: google-oauth

I am running into an issue with one single user's refresh workflow for Google OAuth. I am correctly scoping for offline access and am storing that. Every 60 minutes, when needed, I retrieve a new access_token. Code has not changed, but what is odd is that when he first went through the authorization process it worked for about 3 days. Then we were running this issue, so I made him revoke access and go through the authorization again. This only lasted for 3 days once again.

```
client_id       ="xxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com"
client_secret   ="yyyyyyyy"
refresh_token   ="zzzzzzzz"
response        = oauth2a.RefreshToken(client_id,client_secret,refresh_token)

def RefreshToken(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token):
  params = {}
  params['client_id'] = client_id
  params['client_secret'] = client_secret
  params['refresh_token'] = refresh_token
  params['grant_type'] = 'refresh_token'
  request_url = AccountsUrl('o/oauth2/token')

  response = urllib.urlopen(request_url, urllib.urlencode(params)).read()
  return json.loads(response)
```

The response is always {u'error': u'invalid_grant'}. I have attempted this on three different machines, so the NTP time sync is not the issue as well. All other user's refresh works fine. I am also never asking for a refresh_token again, so I know I'm not running into that 25 refresh_token limit. This is looking like it's a bug on the gmail side, is there any way that I can proceed to try to fix this?

Comment: the 25 token thing is the more likely explanation. Are you sure you don't have a bug that is causing extraneous tokens to be generated. It might be worth looking at the user's account page https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1 and looking at the auth date. I don't know if the date is bumped for each refresh token, but it might give a clue.

Comment: the authorization happens once and only once. I do have an update, approximately 20 hours later it just started returning back a valid grant. there was no code change, nothing. still very confused and would like to know how to prevent this in the future. the fact that it just started working leads me to believe that it's the timing issue but the fact that I tried this on three different machines doesn't make sense either. thoughts?